# Config file gets overwritten in qt

Tags: qt, config

I am writing data to a config file using the following code.

```
   QSettings settings("/root/configFile.ini",QSettings::IniFormat);

   QString userName = lineEditUsername.text();
   QString password = lineEditPassword.text();

   QList<QString> listUsername;
   QList<QString> listPassword;

   settings.beginWriteArray("UserData");

   for(i=0;i<listUsername.size();i++)
  {
      Qstring user = listUsername.at(i);         
      Qstring pass = listPassword.at(i);

      settings.setArryIndex(i);
      settings.setValue("Username",user);
      settings.setValue("Password",pass);
   }

  settings.endArray();
 }
```

Now when I run the code first time and give 4 or 5 values they are formed in proper order in the file. However if I run the application for second time the values start overwriting from first position. Can some one suggest me some solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of creating and maintaining arrays and indexes, I would propose to create user credentials map and store it in the settings file as follows:

```
QSettings settings("/root/configFile.ini", QSettings::IniFormat);

QString userName = lineEditUsername.text();
QString password = lineEditPassword.text();

QList<QString> listUsername;
QList<QString> listPassword;

//settings.beginWriteArray("UserData");

QVariantMap userDataMapping;

for(int i = 0; i < listUsername.size() ; i++)
{
    QString user = listUsername.at(i);         
    QString pass = listPassword.at(i);

    userDataMapping[user] = pass;

    //settings.setArryIndex(i);
    //settings.setValue("Username",user);
    //settings.setValue("Password",pass);
}

// Store the mapping.
settings.setValue("UserData", userDataMapping);

//settings.endArray();
// ...
```

This will store your data in ini file in the following format:

```
UserData=@Variant(\0\0\0\b\0\0\0\x1\0\0\0\x6\0\x64\0\x64\0\x64\0\0\0\n\0\0\0\x6\0\x62\0\x62\0\x62)
```

When you read settings, do something like this:

```
[..]
QVariant v = settings.value("UserData");
QVariantMap map = v.value<QVariantMap>();
QMapIterator<QString, QVariant> i(map);
while (i.hasNext()) {
    i.next();
    QString user = i.key();
    QString pass = i.value().toString();
}
```

Comment: But if I have more data to add to the config file like their roles I wont be able to add it right?

Comment: @user2548968, I don't understand you. Please clarify your question. What is 'roles' and what kind of data are you going to add?

Comment: I tried using this method. I wanted to add extra functionality so I took one more QVariant and did the same thing for it. However while reading it is getting unexpectedly finished.

Comment: Roles is like suppose its a school database and a student is logging in then he will have to define role as Student and similarly for teacher and principal. So even that has to come through config file. I will be taking this value as QString from combo box.

Comment: any more suggestions buddy. 

Still not able to figure out why I am going wrong while reading data. 
Just after i.next I am adding the if condition of 
If(username == user) 
{ 
// rest of the code
} 

In application output it is saying item_exists() in file "opt/QtSDK/....". 

When I debug it gives segmentation fault at QString user = i.key();

Comment: @user2548968, I have fixed the code above: `i.next()` should be called before `i.key()`.

Comment: @Vahancho..Sorry I know I am asking after a lot of days. However I am still getting the same problem. Everytime I run the program the values that I set Over write the old values.

Answer (score 0):

You need to retrieve the amount of existing entries before adding a new one. Something like this:

```
int size = settings.beginReadArray( "UserData" );
settings.endArray();

settings.beginWriteArray( "UserData" );
settings.setArrayIndex( size );  // Note: Maybe 'size - 1', not  sure

// ...
settings.endArray();
```

[setArrayIndex( size )](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qsettings.html#setArrayIndex) will move the array index to the end and will thus no longer override an existing entry